# Compiling mod_auth_token for windows

Tags: windows, apache, module, compilation

I have access to both Windows machine ( Win 7 ) & Linux ( Ubuntu 10.04 ), I would like to know how can I compile mod_auth_token on my Linux machine and get it working on Windows.

**If I take the .so file from the Linux machine will it work on windows??**

Can any one help me out, If you can compile it for me & put it somewhere for download or just let me know a way that will work (I don't have Visual Studio nor any compile related programs on windows that's why I need to do it on Linux then move it over to windows and just link it in the config file).

Version I need help on compiling mod_auth_token-1.0.6-beta

Location: http://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-token/

Comment: Building it on Linux (.so) will not work on windows. You would need to compile a .dll - Try using cygwin

Comment: I have wampserver 64bit installed, and it appears to be using .so files (no .dll file there) so it's weird.

Comment: Sorry my comment was misleading, I meant it will compile it into an ELF shared object library and not the PE format needed for windows. The .so files you are using were probability built using cygwin. The issues list for that project seem to suggest that it can't be built for windows in it's current form.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows version has been released by ApacheHaus recently. They have this module for both Apache 2.2 and 2.4 (x86 and x64 both).

here is the link https://www.apachehaus.net/modules/mod_auth_token/